# error in calculating dates in php functions

Tags: php, strtotime

I am working on a php project where I need to get the all dates for next 20 weeks  from a particular date and I am trying following logic

```
$epochdate = strtotime("17 August 2015");

for ($i=$epochdate + 604800, $i < $epochdate + ( 604800 * 20 ); $i = $i+604800, $j++) { 
   echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $i);
   echo '</br>';
}
```

Everything is working fine but it gave wrong date after 2015-10-19 ..here is the output

```
2015-08-24 00:00:00
2015-08-31 00:00:00
2015-09-07 00:00:00
2015-09-14 00:00:00
2015-09-21 00:00:00
2015-09-28 00:00:00
2015-10-05 00:00:00
2015-10-12 00:00:00
2015-10-19 00:00:00
2015-10-25 23:00:00//it should be 2015-10-26
2015-11-01 23:00:00
2015-11-08 23:00:00
2015-11-15 23:00:00
2015-11-22 23:00:00
2015-11-29 23:00:00
2015-12-06 23:00:00
2015-12-13 23:00:00
2015-12-20 23:00:00
2015-12-27 23:00:00
```

What is wrong here?

Comment: on this date the switch to daylight saving time is made in 2015

Answer (score 5):

This most likely happens because of the transition from standard time to daylight time in some time zones.

Try using the [`DateTime`](https://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) class instead:

```
$epochdate = new DateTime("2015-08-17");
for ($i = 0; $i < 20; $i++) {
  $epochdate->modify('+1 week');
  echo $epochdate->format('Y-m-d H:i-s') . '<br>';
}
```

Output:

```
2015-08-24 00:00-00
2015-08-31 00:00-00
2015-09-07 00:00-00
2015-09-14 00:00-00
2015-09-21 00:00-00
2015-09-28 00:00-00
2015-10-05 00:00-00
2015-10-12 00:00-00
2015-10-19 00:00-00
2015-10-26 00:00-00
2015-11-02 00:00-00
2015-11-09 00:00-00
2015-11-16 00:00-00
2015-11-23 00:00-00
2015-11-30 00:00-00
2015-12-07 00:00-00
2015-12-14 00:00-00
2015-12-21 00:00-00
2015-12-28 00:00-00
2016-01-04 00:00-00
```

If the date comes in the day month year format as in your example you may need to use [`DateTime::createFromFormat()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) first.

Answer (score 3):

Why did you make it so complicated?

For your logic with strtotime() you can just do that

```
 <?php
    $epochdate = "17 August 2015"; 
    for ($i=0; $i<=20; $i++) {
       echo date('Y-m-d H:i', strtotime($epochdate.' +'.$i.' weeks');
       echo "<br>";

    }
```